# C# protobuf with customize attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, protocol-buffers

I wanna generate C# protobuf code with customize attributes.
such as:

```
public sealed partial class LoginIn : pb::IMessage<LoginIn>
  #if !GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
      , pb::IBufferMessage
  #endif
  {
    [mycall] // customize attributes
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute] // original
    public LoginIn() {
      OnConstruction();
    }
   ... // rest code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `partial class`, you can add attributes (and members) to the *type*, but you can't add attributes to individual members, so: you can't do anything simple here. Effectively, you'd need to tweak the code-gen itself (meaning: create your own version of the `protoc` addin), which is far from ideal.

The other option is manually editing the generated code - again: far from ideal.

Before doing either of those, I'd have to ask myself some serious questions about `[mycall]` and how important it is, what it does, and whether adding it to the *serialization model* is necessary, vs creating my own domain model that can have *any attributes you want*, and mapping between the domain model and the serialization model.